# How to plot p-values in a circular barplot?

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2

Im trying to plot reactome pathway in for of circular bar plot using ggplot2

my data

```
    dput(df2)
structure(list(ID = 1:10, Pathway_names = structure(c(5L, 1L, 
7L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 4L), .Label = c("Antigen Presentation: Folding assembly and peptide loading of class I MHC", 
"Antigen processing-Cross presentation", "Class I MHC mediated antigen processing & presentation", 
"Cytokine Signaling in Immune system", "Endosomal/Vacuolar pathway", 
"ER-Phagosome pathway", "Immunoregulatory interactions between a Lymphoid and a non-Lymphoid cell", 
"Interferon alpha/beta signaling", "Interferon gamma signaling", 
"Interferon Signaling"), class = "factor"), Entities_found = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("51", "54", "55", 
"57", "75", "77", "96", "117", "176"), class = "factor"), Entities_pValue = c(1.11e-16, 
1.11e-16, 0.003908431, 2.54e-12, 2.77e-10, 0.0053068, 1.64e-13, 
1.11e-16, 1.11e-16, 3.68e-06)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

my code

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = factor(Pathway_names), y = Entities_found)) + ######################################
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Entities_pValue), stat = "identity", position = "stack") + 
  #scale_fill_manual(values = c(blank = "white", dark = "black")) + 
  coord_polar() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

[image: my output]

So far im not sure how to include both p value and entities in the plot so that the pathway that are coming up can be labeled accordingly

New figure [image: updated figure]

Comment: I don't understand the issue. It looks fine to me.

Comment: What do you mean by entities: the third column of your `df2`? You already have the height for the entities and the color for the p-value. How is this plot not what you expected?

Comment: yes i tried different ways but this is what i end up with  ,but can you suggest me a way to color it so that it can distinguish p value it color scale_manual ?

Comment: @krushnachChandra Sorry I don't understand your question from the comments. You want to distinguish the p-value with the colors? Or do you want to set a manual scale of colors? If the question is the former, you can try to apply `log10`  to the variable to better distinguish the values. If the later case, I don't understand what is your problem with scale_manual

Comment: Can I suggest using acronyms for the entity names in the figure? Like ERPP for ER-Phagosome pathway? This way the text can be placed next to its barplot component and be readable.

Comment: okay let me try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `adjustcolor` function from `grDevices` can be used to generate colours with transparency. What you want is colours based on the pathway and transparency to form a colour gradient for the p-value.

`adjustcolor( "red", alpha.f = 0.2)`

For the ggplot example, the `aes` function has an `alpha` parameter.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = factor(Pathway_names), y = Entities_found), alpha = Entities_pValue) + ######################################
geom_bar(aes(fill = Entities_found, alpha = Entities_pValue), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +  
coord_polar() + 
theme_minimal() + 
 guides(fill = FALSE)
```

Comment: it looks fine now may be i can tweak it a bit more i will see but i see my Entities_found are still 150 but highest one is 176 why am not getting till 176?

Comment: i have a doubt the p value gradient still looks confusing ...can you help me regarding that

Comment: Try plotting them on a log-scale?

Comment: no i haven;t given that thought may be that would help